# Spring Data Rest: is it domain class specific?

Tags: spring, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-rest

How does Spring Data Rest work with those repository which is not particular to single Domain class ?
I mean I have following repository:

```
public interface MyRepository<T extends BaseDomain> extends GraphRepository<T>, PagingAndSortingRepository<T, Long> {
// .....
}
```

And I am getting this url generated by Spring Data REST:

```
http://localhost:8080/amg-web/sdr/baseDomain
```

Here `BaseDomain` is class which is extended by many other sub domain or child domain. So How can I target to those domain while operating through SDR ? Because whenever I am saving any node or entity using above url, into repository its only saving an index of super class i.e. BaseDomain and nothing else.

**Update**
SDR is working fine with Repository if without any generics I mean if particular domain class is assigned to it.

```
public interface MyRepository extends GraphRepository<EntityDomain>, PagingAndSortingRepository<EntityDomain> {  
 //....
}
```

So, I guess SDR is domain class specific !!

Comment: Just curious, Could you able run a test if you were using just Spring Data and others but without Spring-data-rest?

Comment: @Stackee007 Yes.. it works as far as SD Neo4j is concerned.. `MyRepository<EntityDomain> repo` where EntityDomain is subclass of BaseDomain. I think it should work for other too such as Mongodb etc

Comment: I see your update, hence my earlier question. Spring repositories do not expect Generics since the framework does not know how to instantiate those beans.

Comment: @stackee007 you mean SDR context right ? my updated part is for working SDR. else normal autowiring of Spring Repository with Generic also working if not considering SDR. I just wanted to know if we could use SDR with my previous Spring repo with generics.. :)

Answer (score 0):

All abstract classes and interfaces needed to be resolved by Jackson serializer. You can read about this in [SDR documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/representations-chapter.html#d5e377)